# Custom View with Xib as root View

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib

When creating a custom view, is it possible to set the root view as the xib?

Currently if I create a custom view, I need to add the nib as a subview.

If I want to change the background color, I can no longer use the UIView APIs.

```
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // Won't work because nib view is covering the "root" view.
```

So, is it possible to do this..

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    func commonInit() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: getInheritedClassName(object: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        // Currently doing this..
        addSubview(view)
        // Can we do this somehow?
        self = view // Set self as the xib view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use awakeAfter:

```
open override func awakeAfter(using _: NSCoder) -> Any? {
    // set the tag in the view's XIB, so we don't create an infinite loop
    guard tag != 999 else {
        return self
    }

    let view = type(of: self).instantiate() // Convenience method that chooses nib based on class name
    view.frame = frame
    view.autoresizingMask = autoresizingMask
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
    view.tag = tag
    for constraint in constraints {
        let firstItem = constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self ? view : constraint.firstItem
        let secondItem = constraint.secondItem as? UIView == self ? view : constraint.secondItem
        let constraintToAdd = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstItem as Any, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: secondItem, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant)
        constraintToAdd.priority = constraint.priority
        view.addConstraint(constraintToAdd)
    }

    return view
}
```